# Does BIRT support unrelated datasources for one report?

Tags: birt

I have a report which needs to be rewritten in BIRT (currently implemented in crystal).It contains subreports that are completely unrelated to each other. E.g price info is one subreport and dependent info is another subreport. Both of these have no column in common.
Each of the subreport invokes its own SQL and hence has its own result set.Is it possible to have such unrelated datasources  in BIRT?
I have to use XML as datasource.
Thanks in advance!!